# how to get the values from two different sortable values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have more than one sortables created using jquery with same class and id but i'm not getting how to get the values of items in sortable list once the elements and rearranged

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  function submit(){
       var idsInOrder = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");

      alert(idsInOrder);
    }
  </script>

<ul id="sortable" class="sortable" style="margin-left: 319px; width: 217px;" onclick="submit()">
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="Item 1" value="Item 1">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="Item 2" value="Item 2">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="Item 3" value="Item 3">Item 3</li>  
</ul>

<ul id="sortable" class="sortable" style="margin-left: 319px; width:    217px;" onclick="submit()">
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="Item 1" value="Item 1">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="Item 2" value="Item 2">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="Item 3" value="Item 3">Item 3</li>  
</ul>
```

any response is appreciable

Comment: **id** meant to be unique.

Comment: You don't write id's like `Item 1`. They have to be without the space between `Item` and `1`. And of course it's not working, because id's must be always unique.

Comment: is there any way to achieve it without changing id since if i change the id sortable will not work

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ul id="sortable" class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="Item1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="Item2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="Item3">Item 3</li>  
 </ul>
```

Full working solution is [HERE-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1p9xoac) or [HERE-jsbin](https://jsbin.com/tafifi/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: this solution is only for unique id, i want if id's of two elements are same

Comment: @SandeepM.D ID meant to be unique. not sure why you want same ID for multiple elements. Can you tell why you want id of two elements same ?